How to spilt a Python class in multiple files in different subdirectories?
I can split a class definition in multiple files only if these are located in the same directory:
# entrypoint.py

class C(object):

    from ImplFile import OtherMethod

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

# ImplFile.py

def OtherMethod(self):
    print("a = ", self.a)

If the ImplFile.py file is in a subdirectory, I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OtherMethod'

How can I specify that the member function is defined in that file?

The reason I want to split the implementation in more than one file is due to its size, both in terms of number of member functions and their size.

Why would you? it's a terrible idea.

Assuming you have a __init__.py file in there, you can do from xxx.ImplFile import OtherMethod, but don't do that.

If the file is in another subdirectory, you need to know if the module is still a top-level module (in which case the directory needs to be added to the search path) or part of a package (in which case you need to know the full name of the module). Either way, though, it's probably a bad idea to scatter your method definitions across multiple modules.

big question would be how this code is supposed to run, and from where, what's PYTHONPATH ? I can see this reasoning e.g. when you build python package and wish to separate convenience functions from main abstraction - but then you would just use absolute import references.

As mentionned by DeepSpace and Tim Roberts, it's quite bad practice what you're doing mainly because it's difficult to understand what's going on when you're reading your code without any explanations or documentation.
If you really insist on continuing on the same path, simply add the subdirectory's name before the filename in the Import statement:
from <subdirectory>.ImplFile import OtherMethod


If, however, you wish to proceed with a cleaner code, the best option in your case would probably be to use Inheritance.
You can create your Parent Class with the base attributes and methods in you main file and then create Child Classes in other files/subdirectories with additionnal methods/attributes.
